# Allow me to draft a question in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions, android-app, draft

As far as I could see, I can't draft a question in the Stack Exchange Android app. If I press the X to back out of submitting when I next go in, the fields are all blank. Could we have the ability to draft questions, either with an explicit draft button or simply having it persisted when leaving the submit screen?

Ideally this should persist between the website and the app, in both directions.

Comment: This is planned, though it will probably only be a local draft initially

Comment: This pseudo-exists (more as a protection against crashes at the moment). If you kill the app (by pushing it out of the recent apps list) while writing a question, then restart the app and click "ask question" again, it'll still be there.

Comment: The ultimate awesome would be if the draft written in mobile would also appear when I open the question on a browser at desktop computer...

Comment: @David Isn't this [status-completed] now? At least I see my previous typing and a "discard or keep draft?" pop-up after using the back key to exit the ask page.

Comment: @balpha (see above comment ^)

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Yep, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed (a long time ago, really...). If you leave the screen while asking / answering, your draft will automatically be saved and you'll be prompted if you want to continue the next time you come back.