# Implementing a feature to save in real time text written on mobile application

Tags: feature-request, bug, android-app

I suggest implementing a way to save the question/answer you are writing in case that accidentally the app get closed and being able to restore everything if it's wanted.

I was writing a text in which I spent some time writing it and suddenly the app closed. It was really frustrating and I think that it would be a really nice feature to implement

Comment: After some similar experiences, I use the site from browser even on mobile (the mobile version is more ergonomic on smartphone, while the desktop version has all the desktop features, including reviews). Also I think, this app could be done better, but not I have to pay the programmers working on it, thus it is easy for us to give similar advices. ;-) As ordinary users, we can select between the already developed options, or we can use different sites. Although I find it useful if the people says his opinion, because it helps the team to priorize, thus I find also this question useful.

Comment: This [should work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193005/allow-me-to-draft-a-question-in-the-stack-exchange-android-app), but considering the app is falling apart, most likely it's a  bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It may not be a bug in the app causing it to close unexpectedly. One of my mobile iOS devices is so old that newer material often overloads it and the current app closes. Even the Calendar app has been known to dump me. Not claiming the SE app is bug-free, just that it may not be the only possibility.

Comment: @ShadowWizard So currently is it a feature but the problem is that it doesn't work properly?

Comment: On second thought, I think the draft is saved only when you exit the app in organized way, e.g. back button, not on regular intervals. So if it terminates no draft is saved indeed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard So is instead a feature request and not a bug report , right?

Comment: Not 100% sure, better leave both tags.